# I am creating a new library to codeignighter, seem i cannot use/load helper i've created

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

Basically I have a helper file with several function.
I auto load the helper in the config file so theoretically reloading it is not required.

However when I try to use the function that I created(from this helper) within a new library that I am working on it will through this error:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/techwork/public_html/giverhub/application/libraries/Udetails.php on line 7"
```

Whenever I use that function anywhere else(module,controller,views) it works fine.

I then read and thought maybe I should try loading the helper after following instructions at:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

and try referencing and loading but that also through an error:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/techwork/public_html/giverhub/application/libraries/Udetails.php on line 5"
```

Here is the library:

```
class Udetails{

$CI =& get_instance();// referencing as described in their website
$CI->load->helper('mylogin_helper');// loading the helper
public $member_session = is_member(); // using the function 
public $username = $member_session['username'];
public $current_uID = $member_session['id'];
public $member_status = $member_session['status'];
}
```

Here is the function within the helper:

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_member'))
{
    function is_member(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
    $is_logged_in = $CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    $username = $CI->session->userdata('username');
    $capabilities = $CI->session->userdata('capabilities');
    $user_id = $CI->session->userdata('id');
    switch ($capabilities){
        case 'registered':
          $level = 1;
          break;
        case 'confirmed':
          $level = 2;
          break;
        case 'charity_admin':
          $level = 3;
          break;
        case 'admin':
          $level = 4;
          break;
        case 'super_admin':
          $level = 5;
          break;
        default:
          $level = 0;
    }

    $userdetails = array();
    if(isset($is_logged_in) && $is_logged_in == true){
        if($level > 1){
            $userdetails['username'] = $username;
            $userdetails['status'] = TRUE;
            $userdetails['id'] = $user_id;
            return $userdetails;
        }

    }   

}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line has problem

```
public $member_session = is_member();
```

You can't `initialize class variable with function call`. it should have some static value not dynamic

Because of this, you also getting parse error on line 7

**EDIT**

```
class Udetails{

public $username = $member_session['username'];
public $current_uID = $member_session['id'];
public $member_status = $member_session['status'];

public function get_data(){
    $CI =& get_instance();// referencing as described in their website
    $CI->load->helper('mylogin_helper');// loading the helper

    $member_session = is_member(); // using the function 

    $this->username = $member_session['username'];
    $this->current_uID = $member_session['id'];
    $this->member_status = $member_session['status'];

}


}
```

In Controller,

```
$this->load->library('udetails');

echo "<pre>";
 print_r ($this->udetails->get_data());
```

Comment: how can i give the variable dynamic values then ?

Comment: Please use __construct to initialize your class variables

Comment: so basically i just initialize the variable before __construct "public variable; and then in __construct i do $this->member_session = is_member(); ?
how will i then be able to access the value of that variable ?

Comment: So basically there is no way to dynamically define the variable in a way that i could later on use them on other methods in the same class ?

Comment: Alright your answer GBD is partially correct i've read some more and found the correct way. I will post the answer as answer however i will chose your answer as the correct answer because you helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Udetails{

    // initializing variables that will be used in other methods
public $username;
public $current_uID;
public $member_status;

public function __construct(){
    $member_session = is_member();
    $this->username = $member_session['username'];
    $this->current_uID = $member_session['id'];
    $this->member_status = $member_session['status'];
}

// All the gets
    public function anothermethod(){
         //$CI =& get_instance(); - need to load those on each method if needed
         //$CI->load->helper('mylogin_helper'); - need to load those on each method if needed
        //can now use any of the variable deined in the construct in other methods.
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

in the controller:

```
$this->load->library('udetails');
$somevar = $this->udetails->anothermethod();
```

I hope that helps.